# Does $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(a_n\:+\:b_n\right)^2$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to understand if the following holds true

If $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:a{^2}_n$ and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:b{^2}_n$ are two convergent series, does $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(a_n\:+\:b_n\right)^2$ converges?

The series is non-negative and I believe I should use the convergent comparison test in order to determine if it converges, but I feel a bit clueless here.

Comment: Hint: $(a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2+2b^2.$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the inequality you gave?

Comment: Jensen to $(|a|/2+|b|/2)^{2}\leq|a|^{2}/2+|b|^{2}/2$.

Comment: Yes! You have that $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab,$ so the inequality above is true if $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$ which is true if and only if  0\leq a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2.$ But this is true because it is a square so it is non negative.

Comment: @RiccardoCeccon I see it now. Thank you very much! <3

Answer (score 6):

We have $\left(\displaystyle\sum|a_{n}||b_{n}|\right)^{2}\leq\displaystyle\left(\sum|a_{n}|^{2}\right)\left(\sum|b_{n}|^{2}\right)$ and then $|a_{n}+b_{n}|^{2}\leq|a_{n}|^{2}+2|a_{n}||b_{n}|+|b_{n}|^{2}$, so the result follows.

Comment: This holds for complex series as well.

Comment: Not sure I understood this solution. Why can I say that $\left(\sum \left|a_n\right|^2\right)\left(\sum \:\left|b_n\right|^2\right)$ converges?

Comment: If we assume that $\displaystyle\sum|a_{n}|^{2}<\infty$, and this includes your assumption that $a_{n}$ being nonnegative.

Comment: And of course similar assumption made for $|b_{n}|$.